# WCF or Normal BLL which one is a better solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, performance, web-applications, erp

we are going to develop a big web application in MVC 3, and need to improve the Performance and speed of the application, so we have decided to use WCF. But is there a good way to write all our business logic in WCF ? What is a good way to use WCF effectively?

One more problem is that there are a large number of classes, so a large number of service references will need to be added to the project.

**How can i effectively implement WCF for good performance?**

Comment: I fail to see how adding an extra layer, potentially adding a hop over a network, requiring the serializing of data, will make your app faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not better performance to add distribution layer into your app, otherwise, it will slow down performance, more complicated. The first rule of distribution **is not distribution** because you have to deal with: serialization, security....

Think about why you need to make your app distributed, do your app need to be public as services and consume from iSO, Android or WPF. If not, don't use, go ahead with business layer as DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Having an extra physical tier will harm rather than increase raw performance of a request but it may increase scalability and can give you extra options in terms of security architecture. For raw throughput you should use an in memory DLL.

However, you can keep your options open by programming to an abstraction to get the data and then put an in-memory DLL or WCF proxy behind the abstraction if other requirements warrant it